# Click on hidden elements with Selenium java WebDriver, without using the javascript executor?

Tags: java, selenium, click, webdriver, hidden

Is it possible to click on hidden/non-visible elements, using the selenium java webdriver, without using the JavaScript executor to click via JavaScript? The tests I'm performing are in a browser with JavaScript disabled, which is why I can't use the jse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium is meant to replicate the end user's behavior. Since any end user cannot do anything with the hidden element it's not realistic to interact with hidden elements directly. See [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_Why_is_it_not_possible_to_interact_with_hidden_elements?) answer.

So, the answer is No there is no way without the javascript executor. Selenium does not interact with the hidden element directly